# how to override element.style using css

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a xhtml page and i am trying to override the element.style.
[source page view when i inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfAC6.png)

I had tried to apply my own CSS but it didn't work at all.
I have search through the similar question that i face but no one is working for me.

`.element .style {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}`

Anyone have any idea how can i apply my own CSS so that i could override this style.element?

```
    <h:panelGrid id ="cibBulk" styleClass="interfaceDashboard" >
        <h:outputText style="text-align: center;background-color: green;" styleClass= "interfaceTransactionTitle" value="CIB BULK UPLOAD TO HOST" />
        <..../>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

The output of my screen page (the background color not fit at all) would not be what i expected for as the screen attached.
[Output screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJ0x.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSF, but from the screenshots it looks like you need to put the `style` attribute in the `h:outputText`'s parent instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{  
    background-color: green;
}
.element.style {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="element style">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I snip the part of my xhtml page. The snipped code is as below. But the style=" background-color:green;" didn't fit the full on my outputtext.
How can i make it to become full background color of the outputtext?

<h:panelGrid id ="cibBulk" styleClass="interfaceDashboard" >
 <h:outputText style="text-align: center;background-color: green;" value="CIB BULK UPLOAD TO HOST" />
</h:panelGrid>

Answer (score 0):

That is inline CSS style which is used to apply a unique style to a single HTML element.They come from the `style=""` attribute that sets `element.style.someProperty`.

For example :

```
<h1 style="color:blue;">Blue Heading</h1>
```

This will set heading to color blue. If you inspect then you will see like this:

[image]

Like in your snapshot if you want to change the style, you can put `style` attribute in `tbody`. Learn more [here](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles).